# Routing при отображении сайта

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

**Версия**

`"react-router-dom": "^6.3.0"`

Все приложение обернуто в `<BrowserRouter>`

**Роутинг**

```
  <Routes>
      <Route element={<Singlepage data={weather} />}>
        <Route index element={<Main />} />
        <Route path='about' element={<About />} />
        <Route path='forecast' element={<Forecast handleData={handleData} handleCity={handleCity} />} />
        <Route path='done' element={<Done />}>
          <Route path='current' element={<Current data={weather} />} />
          <Route path='day' element={<Day data={weather} />} />
          <Route path='week' element={<Week data={weather} />} />
        </Route>
        <Route path='error' element={<Error data={city} />} />
      </Route>
    </Routes>
```

При обновлении страницы (на хостинге) (прим. **домен/имя_страницы)** выскакивает 404 (страница не найдена).

Если же оборачиваю в `<HashRouter>` страницы отображаются, но через якорь # (прим. **домен/#/имя_страницы)**

Есть ли возможность избавиться от /#/? или статичные сайты без бекенда только через `<HashRouter>`

Comment: укажите в вопросе какую версию react-router вы используете

Comment: @Алексей     "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",